# load multiple 3d models xna in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I try the following code to load XNA 3D model in winforms, this code works done when load only one model but when try to load more than one model must load only one in dynamic way and the others in static way by put their path. 
this is my code to load a model

```
void LoadModel(string fileName)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            // Unload any existing model.


            editorDesign1.Model = null;


            contentManager.Unload();

            // Tell the ContentBuilder what to build.
            contentBuilder.Clear();
            contentBuilder.Add(fileName, "Model", null, "ModelProcessor");

            // Build this new model data.
            string buildError = contentBuilder.Build();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildError))
            {
                // If the build succeeded, use the ContentManager to
                // load the temporary .xnb file that we just created.
              editorDesign1.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
              // editorDesign1.CurrentModel.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
            }
            else
            {
                // If the build failed, display an error message.
                MessageBox.Show(buildError, "Error");
            }

            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
```

and to show multiple model must make this

```
 m1.Model = content.Load<Model>("watcher");
```

so the result will be show `watcher` model and the other model loaded in dynamic way.
and this is the way how i draw the model

```
public void DrawModel()
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(Rotation.X) * Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(Rotation.Y) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation.Z);

                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```

How to solve this problem ? can any one give me a bit of code or link ?

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you do 
m1.Model = content.Load<Model>("watcher"); 
m2.Model = content.Load<Model>("watcher2");

Comment: @StefanAgartsson i want the two model be in the same game

Comment: That's no problem, you need to store the model on two different objects of the Model type. What are m1?

Comment: @StefanAgartsson m1 is an object from class mymodel where make every property for the model scale and rotate and others `mymodel m1; `and my class `class mymodel : DrawableGameComponent
    {`

Comment: The loading isn't the problem, you are storing to the same object some how. Create two objects Model myModel1; Model myModel2; That will work better.